# No puedo obtener la URL de mi imagen en la versión angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, typescript

Estoy usando FireStorage en mi proyecto Angular en la versión Angular CLI: 11.2.6 pero cuando obtengo la URL de la imagen cargada con el comando **this.dowloadUrl.getDownloadURL ()**

Tengo un texto de entrada en el que lo muestro pero no puedo obtener esos datos para poder operarlo.

```html
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { UploadScriptsService } from 'src/app/services/upload-scripts.service';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
/*importo el servicio conectionService para mandar datos*/
import { ConectionService } from 'src/app/services/conection.service';
/*importo el Storage de firebase */
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-card',
  templateUrl: './add-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-card.component.css']
})
export class AddCardComponent implements OnInit {


  private script: UploadScriptsService = new UploadScriptsService;
  @ViewChild('imageUser') inputImageUser: ElementRef | undefined;

  /*Variables con las cuales envio los datos para cargar a firebase*/
  item: any = {
    title: '',
    text: '',
    image: ''
  };

  imageSrc: string = "";
  userFile: any;
  imageSelected: any;

/*  DECLARO LAS VARIABLES PARA PODER ENVIAR LA IMAGEN Y OBTENER SU URL */
  imgUrl: Observable<string | any>; 
  uploadPercent: Observable<number | any>; 
  

  constructor(private conection: ConectionService, private storage: AngularFireStorage) {
    this.uploadPercent = new Observable;
    this.imgUrl = new Observable;
  }

  


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.script.cargaScripts(["uploadCard"])
  }


  addCard() {
    this.conection.addCard(this.item);
    this.item.title = '';
    this.item.text = '';
    this.item.image = '';

  }

  onUpload(e: any)  {
    /* console.log("subir", e.target.files[0]); */

    const id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const filePath = `imagesCards/${id}`;
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
    //Subo la foto
    const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);
    //observo el porcentaje de la carga de la imagen
    this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();

    //obtengo el url de la foto
    task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      finalize(() => { 
        this.imgUrl = fileRef.getDownloadURL()
      })
      )
      .subscribe()
      
      console.log('My ImageUrl' + this.imgUrl);

  }



}
```

En mi HTML utilizo un **<input type = "text>"** donde muestro la URL de la imagen que subí, pero no sé cómo hago para obtener esa URL y usarla para subirla a **Cloud Firestore** adjunte la parte del código HTML con una imagen de visualización corta.

```html
 <input #imageUser
  type="text"
  style="margin-top:auto;"
  [value]="urlImage | async">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

En tu codigo primero estas setiando el variable 'imgUrl' con un Observable, despues de que subes la imagen y recibes el url, vuelves a setear el variable 'imgUrl' con un 'string'... tienes que setiarlo con otro Observable... puedes utilizar 'of'

arriba en tu codigo...

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

despues en tu codigo...

```
finalize(() => { 
    this.imgUrl = of(fileRef.getDownloadURL())
  })
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda pero tengo una duda, puedo enviar ese url a una base de datos de la siguiente forma?

**<input id="imageCard"
          type="text"
           style="margin-top:auto;"
           (click)="onChange()"
            [value]="imgUrl | async"
            name="image" 
            [(ngModel)]="item.image">**

Comment: al momento de hacer lo que me dices no me aparece la URL de la imagen, osea mi problema persiste en que la URL la obtengo, pero no logro subir esa URL a mi base de datos en Firebase, en el comentario de arriba tengo la parte de código del HTML en donde trato de subir esa URL pero no la sube, sube un string en blanco.


y no sé como hacer para poder subir el valor que obtengo al momento de hacer **[value]="imgUrl | async"** porque después, lo siguiente que hago es **[(ngModel)]="item.image"** en donde trato de pasar ese String al TypeScript para luego subir la información

Comment: En mi opinion, subir la URL como indicas en tu primer comentario no es la mejor solucion. Que data te regresa cuando haces: task.snapshotChanges().subscribe( data => { console.log(data) //<-- esta data deberia contener el url a la imagen, de alli puedes subir directamente a tu base de datos})

Comment: te entiendo lo que me dices, pero realmente no sé como hacer eso, es decir, con todo el respeto si tomo y pego la parte en la que me dices que de una vez suba la URL puede servir?.

No entiendo muy bien como hacer esa parte y realmente me encuentro atorado en esa parte para poder continuar con el proyecto, te agradecería un montón si me pudieras explicar la forma de hacerlo o en caso dado de explicarme de otra forma, debido a que no entiendo muy bien que me quieres decir y la verdad no sé como hacerlo.

Te agradecería un montón, Gracias Amigo.

Comment: podria ayudarte mostrandote un ejemplo en Stackblitz. Dejame saber si puedes acceder a este url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-udgbd3?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: si puedo ingresar al url, te agradezco mucho tu ayuda.

Comment: Voy a revisar y a comprender lo que aparece en la url

Comment: Estuve revisando y no entiendo la parte donde esta el siguiente codigo

**task
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        first(),
        finalize(() => {
          fileRef
            .getDownloadURL()
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(url => {
              this.url = url;**

esas variables de **url** sin el **this** hacen referencia a la misma variable que creaste arriba como publica?

Es que yo veo que creaste una publica y yo uso un observable, además no se mucho sobre angular y firebase y comprendo como lo haces pero no entiendo :(

Comment: No. `.subscribe(url` es el valor que manda firebase. Despues en `this.url = url` se asigna ese valor a la propiedad publica para poder utilizarla en el template. Ese valor ya no es un observable, es un `string`... La unica razon por la que asigno ese valor es para mostrar la imagen en la pagina. Para guardar el valor a la base de datos, le pasamos el valor a la funcion que se encarga de eso.

Comment: ya te entendí, pero me sale un error de que no encuentra la imagen con el id estipulado.

Porque estuve revisando tu código muy bien y a mi no me sirve la opción en donde el método onUpload() lo tienes sin evento, lo intente hacer así pero no logro obtener la parte de donde capturo Files[0]

Comment: bajo `app.module.ts` tienes que cambiar las credenciales a tu projecto de firebase. Ademas he modificado `app.component.ts` para que trabaje con el evento.